# Electrostatic Shielding: are we fully secure

Tags: electrostatics

Well we know that if you are inside a car you are shielded from electric field due to  lightning. But my question is if you are inside the car and touching any metal which is covering the outside of car , will you get shock or not .
I mean similarly if we are inside a large spherical hollow conductor having charge Q, touching the outer metal surface will we get a shock . I think no!!! because the potential difference between the surface and just inside is almost 0 and potential is kQ/r where k is coloumb's constant.
Am I right.

Answer (score 0):

A conducting sphere may be protection against a high electric field, but it is less effective against current. Any current across it tends to divide between paths according to their impedance. Since both the sphere's impedance and yours are finite, some of the current will choose you. You do not need a great proportion of a 10 KA current to kill you, and that is not a large strike.

A car body, being full of holes, tends to have higher impedance than a sphere and so offers less protection still.

Lying flat on the ground a short distance from the vehicle will improve your chances, as the lightning will be more attracted to the taller, more conductive object. Even if it is a classic sportster with a composite shell (maybe a Reliant Scimitar or (Clan Crusader), or not there at all, lying down is still your best bet.